# How to embed a SilverLight control in ASP.NET control (user or custom)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, vs-web-application-project

We have a ASP.NET web application written in VB.NET where we build content programmatically during the `Init` event.

We make extensive use of user controls, building them on the fly, and I now want to start including SilverLight content.

Is there an easy way of embedding a SilverLight application in a control, and then instantiating the whole thing in code, in the same way as you'd programmatically add ordinary ASP.NET controls to a page?

The SilverLight component itself works fine when added to a page using the `<object>` tag but I really want to be able to reuse it elsewhere in code.

Since I'm expecting use of SilverLight to increase in our application, and the `asp:Silverlight` control seems now to be [deprecated](http://forums.asp.net/t/1446551.aspx), I'm looking for an alternative way of wrapping the content.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own version of the deprecated Silverlight control - all it has to do is emit the appropriate `<object>` html during its `Render` event. This is a really straight forward 5 minute task to roll one of these up.

Comment: Usually when someone says something's a 5 minute task, I go 'yeah right', and wait for the pain to start.  But this time, it really was.  Thanks very much indeed!!